# issue with submitChanges() inserting unwanted records in linq

Tags: linq, tracking, submitchanges, insertonsubmit

I am using LINQ to insert records in the database. I create these records and keep track of them using a List. Based on some logic, I delete some of the records by deleting from the List. (I am using the same DataContext object).

When I want to insert the records in the database, I do the corresponding linq table's InsertOnSubmit() followed by SubmitChanges() on datacontext object. LINQ inserts the deleted-from-List records too along with the ones that are present in the list.

example:

```
//list to keep track of records to insert
List list

// add the records to list
list.add(some records)

//deleted last 2 records
list.remove()

//call InsertAllOnSubmit on the linq table passing the list object with records to insert
linqTable.InsertAllOnSubmit(list)

//call SubmitChanges on datacontext object
datacontext.SubmitChanges()
```

I came across this msdn article [Object States and Change-Tracking (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386982.aspx)

> You can explicitly request Inserts by
>   using InsertOnSubmit. Alternatively,
>   LINQ to SQL can infer Inserts by
>   finding objects connected to one of
>   the known objects that must be
>   updated. For example, if you add an
>   Untracked object to an
>   EntitySet(TEntity) or set an
>   EntityRef(TEntity) to an Untracked
>   object, you make the Untracked object
>   reachable by way of tracked objects in
>   the graph. While processing
>   SubmitChanges, LINQ to SQL traverses
>   the tracked objects and discovers any
>   reachable persistent objects that are
>   not tracked. Such objects are
>   candidates for insertion into the
>   database.

I guess the question boils down to this - how do I change the deleted objects' state to 'Untracked'?

I tried DeleteOnSubmit after I delete the objects from list but that gives an exception (Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached).

Can someone please point me to a solution? Thanks.

I would like to know if I can achieve this using LINQ only. (I know that I can use an stored proc and insert only the records in the list.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the elements of your list are not being removed, because the [List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) method determines equality using the default equality comparer.

If you don't want to write a custom comparer, I recommend you to use the [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method, which receives a predicate as its first parameter to match the elements that will be removed from the list:

```
list.RemoveAll( e=> /*condition to remove the element*/ );
```

Or the [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) method, that removes the element based on the specified index:

```
list.RemoveAt(0); // Delete first element
```

Comment: That's not it. The list's remove() works correctly - I hold a reference to the items I want to remove. The records inserted in the database are greater than the records in the list.

Comment: Also another point to note is that LINQ to SQL traverses the tracked objects *while processing SubmitChanges* (and not while the records are added or deleted) and discovers any reachable persistent objects that are not tracked. Which means even if I change the state of the unwanted records to 'Untracked' explicitly while I delete them, they would still be discovered when SubmitChanges is eventually called later.